# How do I add class to label when radio button is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML radio buttons and I need to add 'checked' as the class of the label when the relevant radio button is selected. The code below works for clicks, but I also need the class added if one of the buttons is selected without clicking, i.e. if the radio button was already selected when the page loaded.

```
<label><input name="radio" type="radio">One</label><br/>
<label><input name="radio" type="radio">Two</label>
```

Here's the js:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('label').click(function(){ 
        $('label').removeClass('checked'); 
        $(this).addClass('checked');
    });

    });
```

Comment: "if the radio button was already selected when the page loaded." means something is going to select it while loading, => that same thing can add the class

Comment: PHP had already added `checked="checked"` to one of the radio buttons. The above code doesn't add the class in this situation.

Comment: ah yes, unless its from php :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add:

```
$('input:checked').parent().addClass('checked');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5ovLtdfn/)**

Comment: @Vega - Don't sweat it. I know the scenario you were thinking of.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to initialize your labels when the document is ready:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var inputs = $('input[type=radio]');
    inputs.change(function () {
        changeLabelClass(this);
    });
    
    //initialize the labels
    changeLabelClass(inputs)
});

function changeLabelClass(radio) {

    //remove the 'checked' class from all labels
    $('input[type=radio]').closest('label').removeClass('checked')
    
    if ($(radio).is(':checked')) 
        $(radio).closest('label').addClass('checked')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
    <input name="radio" type="radio" checked>One</label>
<br/>
<label>
    <input name="radio" type="radio">Two</label>
```